# Sending double type data from fragment to fragment showing null pointer exception

Tags: android

I have MapActivity & LocationSendActivity which extends from fragment.
When Passing double type  data from MapActivity to LocationSendActivity it shows error **"java.lang.NullPointerException".Data in MapActivity**

```
 LocationSendActivity frag=new LocationSendActivity();
        Bundle bnd1=new Bundle();
        bnd1.putDouble("lat", latitude);
        bnd1.putDouble("lng", longitude);
        frag.setArguments(bnd1);
```

Data in LocationActivity is

```
Bundle bnd=this.getArguments();
        latt=bnd.getDouble("lat");
        lngt=bnd.getDouble("lng")
```

MapActivity..........

```
package com.example.map;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.wifi.WifiManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

public class MapActivity extends Fragment {
    private GoogleMap gmap;
    public SupportMapFragment smf;
    public double latitude,longitude;
    public static View view;
    private FragmentManager fm;
    public boolean wifi,gps,network,val;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (view != null) {
            ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            if (parent != null)
                parent.removeView(view);
         }
        try{
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map, container, false);

        try{
            initializemap();
            gmap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            gmap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
            gmap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);

            // Get LocationManager object from System Service LOCATION_SERVICE
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

            // Create a criteria object to retrieve provider
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

            // Get the name of the best provider
            String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

            // Get Current Location
            Location myLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

            //set map type
            //gmap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);

            // Get latitude of the current location
            latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

            // Get longitude of the current location
            longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

            // Create a LatLng object for the current location
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);      

            // Show the current location in Google Map        
            gmap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));

            // Enable / Disable Compass icon
            gmap.getUiSettings().setCompassEnabled(true);

            // Enable / Disable Rotate gesture
            gmap.getUiSettings().setRotateGesturesEnabled(true);

            //Set zooming control on goole to view location
            gmap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 15));

           //Add marker at current position
             MarkerOptions marker=new MarkerOptions();
             marker.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arr));
           //marker.position(latLng).anchor(1,1).rotation(90);
             gmap.addMarker(marker.position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).title("You are here!"));
           //Remove default marker
           //gmap.clear();  
            }catch(Exception e){
                 e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }catch (InflateException e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
        //Dialog call
        showDialog();
        Log.e("latlng", Double.toString(latitude));
        //Set data for LocationSendActivity
        LocationSendActivity frag=new LocationSendActivity();
        Bundle bnd1=new Bundle();
        bnd1.putDouble("lat", latitude);
        bnd1.putDouble("lng", longitude);
        frag.setArguments(bnd1);

        return view;
    }

    public void showDialog() {
        //Check network
         LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
         try{
             network = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
            }catch(Exception ex){}
        //Check Wifi
         WifiManager wfm =(WifiManager)getActivity().getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
         wifi = wfm.isWifiEnabled();
        //Check Gps
        try{
            gps = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            }catch(Exception ex){}

        //call dialog class
        val=network && wifi && gps;
        if(!val){
            DialogFragment dial =new  AlertDialogFragment();
            Bundle bnd=new Bundle();
            bnd.putBoolean("net", network);
            bnd.putBoolean("wi", wifi);
            bnd.putBoolean("gps",gps);
            dial.setArguments(bnd); 
            dial.show(getFragmentManager(),"dialogShow");   
        }                                 
    }

    public void onResume(){
        super.onResume();
        initializemap();
    } 

    private void initializemap() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(gmap == null){
            fm=getFragmentManager();
            Fragment ft=fm.findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            smf=(SupportMapFragment)ft;
            gmap=smf.getMap();  

        } 
    } 

}



LocationSendActivity...........
   package com.example.map;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class LocationSendActivity extends Fragment {

    private double latt,lngt;
    private TextView tv1,tv2;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bnd=this.getArguments();
        latt=bnd.getDouble("lat");
        lngt=bnd.getDouble("lng");  
    }

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        View v=inflater.inflate(R.layout.locationsend, container, false);
    /*  tv1=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        tv1.setText(String.valueOf(latt));
        tv2=(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        tv2.setText(String.valueOf(lngt));  */

        return v;
    }

}
```

LogCat........

```
11-30 12:46:34.238: W/System.err(5880): java.io.IOException: Permission denied
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at com.example.map.LocationSendActivity.onCreate(LocationSendActivity.java:18)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate(Fragment.java:1455)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:893)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1460)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:440)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4635)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:916)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:674)
11-30 12:46:34.248: E/AndroidRuntime(5880):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 12:46:34.258: I/global(5880): Default buffer size used in BufferedWriter constructor. It would be better to be explicit if an 8k-char buffer is required.
```

Comment: Did you log or watch the value of the doubles to make sure they are assigned when you put them in the bundle? Also are you sure that the bundle you set is the same one being received where you think it is? IF when you send the bundle it successfully has the doubles in it, then and when you try to get the doubles out of the bundle they aren't there, you either emptied the bundle, or it is a different bundle. If they are there in the bundle when you try to get them out, then we need more info to help you.

Comment: When i try to find argument in LocationSendActivity it shows error for line    latt=bnd.getDouble("lat");
        lngt=bnd.getDouble("lng");

Comment: Can you also show the activity code that is calling this fragments because it seems that you have created a new object of LocationSendActivity and set arguments to that but fragment was created from a different object from your activity.